# Using a variable to query sys.servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running this from SQL Server 2008 R2.

Is it possible to use a variable name when writing a query to query from sys.servers?

```
DECLARE @hostname varchar(20)
SET @hostname = '192.168.110.101'
SELECT TOP(10) * FROM [@hostname].databasename.dbo.tablename
```

return "Could not find server '@hostname' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.".

It appears that it is trying literally use @hostname and not what the variable is actually set to.  I have also tried removing the brackets and this do not work either.  Any ideas?

Comment: you will have to execute some dynamic sql.

Comment: You will need to use dynamic sql for this.

Comment: This does not appear to work.  Am I doing something wrong?:
`code`DECLARE @sql as NVARCHAR(100);
`code`SET @sql = N'SELECT * from [@hostname].xstore.dbo.trn_trans'
`code`EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @sql, @params = N'@hostname as varchar(25)', @hostname = '192.168.1.1'

Comment: I posted an example below of how to do it in dynamic sql\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SQL as varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM '
DECLARE @hostname varchar(20)
SET @hostname = '192.168.110.101'
SET @SQL = SQL + @hostname + '.databasename.dbo.tablename'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I am getting this: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '192.168'.

Comment: Ok let me look into it... Sorry about that

Comment: I was missing the (AT) symbol after SET (AT)SQL = SQL